# New branch on GIT project behavior

Tags: android, git, android-studio, android-studio-2.0

I created a new GIT repository enabling VCS for my project in Android Studio, made first commit, then created from master a new branch by right clicking on master and choosing New Branch option.

Automatically it checked out the new branch. Ok.

Then I changed a source on working folder, automatically reflected on Local Changes. Ok.

But when I checked out back the master branch I saw on the source on working directory the same change that I made on the new branch.
Even `git status` reports the same file as modified in the master branch.
As the HEAD was left on both the branches.

I am new on GIT, is this a normal behavior?

Comment: I have seen this behavior in Git plugins, such as Eclipse's eGit.  Even though your setup may be allowing it, I would advise avoiding relying on it.  Instead, use proper etiquette and make sure your working tracked directories are clean before switching branches.

Comment: then, if I make the first commit on the new branch, the coupling stops.